# How to manage partial dates with django-partial-date and SelectDateWidget?

Tags: django, forms

I have to manage partial date

I have declare a date as PartialDateField() in my model and I want to render this date as 3 differents select in my form so I use SelectDateWidget

But doing that, form validation failed

is it possible?
how shoud I manage partial date in forms?

```
class mymodel(models.Model):

    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE
    ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    dat = PartialDateField("my date", null=True, blank=True)
    log = HistoricalRecords()
```

```
class myform(forms.ModelForm):

    dat = forms.DateField(
        label= "my date", 
        widget=forms.Select()
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = mymodel
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

try in model

```
dat = PartialDateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

in forms

```
from django.forms import Select

class myform(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = mymodel
    fields = "__all__"
    labels = {'dat': _('my date'),}
    widgets = {
    'dat': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }), ###or ur html class
    }
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I don't have acess to Select() in class Meta...